# Does MarkLogic provides schematron support?

Tags: marklogic

I am using MarkLogic 8.0-8 version.

Is it possible to validate an XML using schematron?

Please help me with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as of MarkLogic 9.0.7, there is built-in support for Schematron.

http://docs.marklogic.com/schematron

> To use the schematron XQuery library module as part of your own XQuery module, include the following lines in your XQuery prolog:

```
    import module namespace schematron = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron"
        at "/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy";
```

For more information and usage examples, see the [Validating Schemas Using Schematron](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/loading_schemas#id_87979) section in the Application Developers Guide.

Answer (score 2):

There are XSLT stylesheets that are publicly available here to run Schematron validation:

https://github.com/Schematron/schematron

You can run these within MarkLogic. Though a little dated, here a project that shows how you could do it. It might still work:

https://github.com/ndw/ML-Schematron

HTH!

Comment: The convenience methods in ML-Schematron compile the schematron into XSLT on every invocation of `sch:validate-document()`. For improved performance, compile the SCH into an XSLT with `sch:compile-schema()` and insert the compiled XSLT into the Modules database once, and then run that for normal Schematron validation routines of your documents.

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic also packages a version of the Schematron validator with the appservices libraries. You can simply import it into a module:

```
import module namespace sch = "http://marklogic.com/validate" 
at "/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/validate.xqy"; 

sch:schematron($document, $schema)
```

Comment: I didn't see any logic in that module that would take care of resolving `sch:include` or `sch:extend`. It looks as if this particular implementation expects the Schematron patterns and rules to all be in a single Schematron file. So, your mileage may vary, or you may still need to pre-compile your Schematron with `iso_abstract_expand.xsl` and `iso_dsdl_include.xsl`.

Comment: @MadsHansen That is my understanding.