# schematron module not found error in qconsol?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I am getting module not found error, while compiling the someSchema.sch Schematron document and insert the generated validator XSLT into the Modules database.

The following line throwing error:

> import module namespace schematron = >"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/schematron" at "/MarkLogic/schematron/schematron.xqy";

Does marklogic 8 support schematron?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MarkLogic provides schematron support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192344/does-marklogic-provides-schematron-support)

Answer (score 3):

No. Schematron support was added in ML 9.0-7